# How to Restore an IBM DB2 database without backup file

Tags: db2, websphere

I need restore a DB2 database of Websphere portal to another server, but I don't have a backup file, I have only a folder NODE0000 (image here => https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7UpL.jpg).

How can I restore this database to another server with this folder?

My environment: CentOS 7 - IBM DB2 9.1 (installed fix pack 4)
Thank a lot!

Comment: Why can't you make the Db2-backup?

Comment: Could you comment on your experience with Db2? Without a backup and an unsupported version of Db2 and no details of the new server there is a lot room for problems.

Comment: This is the first that I work with IBM DB2 :( I need convert data from DB2 to another database, so that I have to restore old DB2 database for view data. But I don't have backup file because old server was died :(
Can anyone help me? I have ínstalled DB2 9.1 on new server (CentOS 7.0) same as environtment of old server. But I don't know how to restore it'

Comment: Do you know the original full path to the `NODE0000` directory? If not, then try to get it from `sqldbdir`. It's a binary file, but you should be able to see it in some text editor.

Comment: yes, I have viewed sqldbdir file and see that the original path is /home/db2inst1/db2inst1

Comment: Actually, the sqldbdir file of a local database path should contain the `/home/db2inst1` string (not `/home/db2inst1/db2inst1`) for the real path `/home/db2inst1/db2inst1/NODE0000` of this `NODE0000` directory. This is because for whatever local database path `/some/path` you specified in the `CREATE DATABASE` command (which is placed into the `sqldbdir` file), the `/some/path/${DB2INSTANCE}/NODE0000` directory structure is created with files an directories like you showed inside.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is similar to cloning database using a split mirror. You can try following steps

- Create instance db2inst1 on new machine if it is not created during db2 installation
- Copy NODE0000 directory to location /home/db2inst1/db2inst1
- Set owner to db2inst1 for directory NODE0000 and all sub-directories and files under NODE0000
- Catalog database you want to access. Example: db2 catalog db commdb on /home/db2inst1
- Connect to database

Comment: Excellent! it is successfully! I don't think it is simple that :D Thank you so much!

Comment: You should do some basic checks like `db2 connect to mydb; db2 list tablespaces` to be sure, that all of your tablespaces are accessible (look at their `State`). Some of the tablespace containers paths may be defined outside of this /home/db2inst1/db2inst1/NODE0000 directory.

Comment: Websphere has 6 databases (COMMDB, CUSTDB, FDBKDB, JCRDB, LMDB, RELDB), but I can not restore FDBKDB, can not connect this DB from IDM DataStudio. I don't know why, the remaining 5 databases, I have restored successfully